# Getting an error while running jenkins job to deploy java application to tomcat server using Ansible template

Tags: jenkins, tomcat, ssh, ansible

**I am getting the following error using ansible playbook**

### **Ansible Playbook:**

- hosts: all_hosts
  become: true
  tasks:

  - name: copy jar/war onto tomcat servers
    copy:
      src: /opt/playbooks/wabapp/target/webapp.war
      dest: /opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.54/webapps
    **Error in jenkins**
    SSH: Connecting with configuration [Ansible] ...
    SSH: EXEC: STDOUT/STDERR from command [ansible-playbook /opt/playbooks/file.yml] ...
    ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
    mapping values are not allowed in this context

The error appears to be in '/opt/playbooks/file.yml': line 6, column 13, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```
- name: copy jar/war onto tomcat servers
    copy:
        ^ here
```

SSH: EXEC: completed after 801 ms
SSH: Disconnecting configuration [Ansible] ...
ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Exec exit status not zero. Status [4]]
Build step 'Send files or execute commands over SSH' changed build result to UNSTABLE
Finished: UNSTABLE

Comment: This is a syntax error in yml file. Mostly because of incorrect spaces.
Can you post your code of yml file as a "code" ? You simply have to edit the question. This helps everyone read the code better, and eventually finding the errors.

Comment: Please provide your Ansible code. It is not 100% clear what causes the issue just by looking at the error message.